# jquery: mouseout applies to nested elements

Tags: jquery, nested, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseout

`ul` with links nested in a div layer. mouse pointer goes over `.title`, `ul` is shown.

the problem: `mouseout()` applies to nested elements

`mouseout()` is for the `div`

```
<div>
  <a class="title">Section A</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href=''>link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>link 3</a></li>
     </ul> 
</div>
```

```
$('.title').mouseover(function() {
   $('ul').slideDown();
})

$('div').mouseout(function(){
   $('ul').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `$('selector').mouseleave(function(){});`