# Why this mouseout will be called when i move out of li instead of ul?

Tags: jquery, mouseout

i want to call mouseout of ul tag, but it looks it will call mouseout as well when i move between two li tags, what's wrong? how can i make it work when i move mouse out of the ul? thanks a lot!

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#info").live("mouseout", function(){
                  console.log('mouseout');

            });
        });
```

HTML

```
    <div id="latest">
        <ul id="info">
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39H7R/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867128/jquery-mouseout-applies-to-nested-elements

Answer (score 1):

Try using like:

```
$('#info').mouseleave(function(){});
```

Hope it helps